# Why my application crash on applicationDidEnterBackground?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have a *static method* called `writeToServer` that is called when application enter in **background mode**.

in my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *) application {
    [LogZone writeToServer];
    NSLog(@"Log sended to server. Done.");
}
```

in my `LogZone.m`:

```
+ (void) writeToServer {
    NSString *qStr = [[NSString alloc]
        initWithFormat:@"%@?ip=%@&uid=%@&platform=%@&model=%@&lat=%@&lon=%@",
            LOG_SERVER_URL,
            _LOG_IP, _LOG_UID, _LOG_PLAT, _LOG_MOD, _LOG_LAT, _LOG_LON];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:qStr]];    
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
}
```

Uppercase vars are static strings created in this way:

.h

```
extern NSString* _LOG_UID;
```

.m

```
NSString* _LOG_UID = @"-1";
```

When I enter in background mode it crash with this "*classic*" error:

> *** -[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance
>   0x6a4c800

But why?
*I don't release anything!=!*

**What's wrong?**

Comment: post the stack trace from the debugger.

Comment: i'm not able. it show me only "2011-01-22 21:02:02.314 myApp[8709:207] *** -[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6942bf0" on this line: "NSString *qStr[...]"

Comment: Note that objective-c does not have *static* methods....

Comment: We have an ARC developer in our midst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why?
>   *I don't release anything!*

Sure, but do you retain the right objects?

Retaining at the right time is every bit as important as not releasing at the wrong time...

Comment: Right. +1! I solved adding a retain to my vars. (_LOG_IP = [[Device getIPAddress] retain];). It works, thanks.

Comment: Excellent.  I hope you added the appropriate release, if needed, too!

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use the following:

```
NSString *qStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?ip=%@&uid=%@&platform=%@&model=%@&lat=%@&lon=%@", LOG_SERVER_URL, _LOG_IP, _LOG_UID, _LOG_PLAT, _LOG_MOD, _LOG_LAT, _LOG_LON];
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with the crash.

Comment: As expected.  It would resolve a likely leak, but definitely not the crash.